# Add file if non-existed, otherwise just update the date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given table as follows:

```
                    datetime label_file
0 2021-04-16 21:18:01.261623   test.csv
```

`datetime` is the current date time and `label_file` is the file name.

Now if I want to add a new file with current date, if it is an existing file name (say `test.csv`), I would just update the `datetime` to latest date time, otherwise I would create a new entry as such:

```
                    datetime label_file
0 2021-04-16 21:18:01.261623   test.csv
1 2021-04-17 21:18:01.261623  test1.csv
```

How should I do that?

The code for original table is as follows:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"datetime":[pd.datetime.now()],"label_file":["test"]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `append` and make use of `drop_duplicates` to keep only last in case there is duplicates for `label_file`

```
df.append(new_files).drop_duplicates(subset="label_file" , keep="last" , ignore_index =True )
```